# Python Dictionary Multiplying Keys * Values

Tags: python, dictionary

Hey everyone trying to multiply the keys * values within a python dictionary.

I have the following code:

```
dic = {'coca-cola':3, 'fanta':2}
def inventory(data):
  lis = []
  lis = [key * val for key, val in data.items()]
  return lis
inventory(dic)
```

However my output is

```
['coca-colacoca-colacoca-cola', 'fantafanta']
```

and I would like to get

```
['coca-cola', 'coca-cola', 'coca-cola', 'fanta', 'fanta']
```

Please Help

Comment: `[key  for key, val in data.items() for i in range(val)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because multiplication of string doesnt return what you excpacted, it multiply the string into a one longer string, you better use the piece of code @deadshot suggested:

```
def inventory(data):
   return [key  for key, val in data.items() for i in range(val)]
```

the output would be as you expacted...

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```
dic = {'coca-cola':3, 'fanta':2}
def inventory(data):
  lis = []

  for key, val in data.items():
      for item in range(0,val):
          lis.append(key)
  return lis
```

Answer (score -1):

Multiplying a `str` by an `int` (as in your original attempt) will simply return a `str` of repetitions of the original `str`. e.g. `3 * 'hi' = 'hihihi'`.

Instead you want to return a `list` where each `key` from your `dict` is stored `val` number of times for each `key`:`value` pair in your `dict`. The below `list` comprehension does this.

**Solution**

```py
def inventory(data):
  return [key for key, val in data.items() for i in range(val)]

dic = {'coca-cola':3, 'fanta':2}
print(inventory(dic))
```

**Output**

```
['coca-cola', 'coca-cola', 'coca-cola', 'fanta', 'fanta']
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello I found this if you want solve your problem:

```py
dic = {'coca-cola':3, 'fanta':2}
def inventory(data):
  lis = []
  lis = [[key]* val for key, val in data.items()]
  return lis
print (inventory(dic))
```

and you get this :

```
[['coca-cola', 'coca-cola', 'coca-cola'], ['fanta', 'fanta']]
```